# Prove $\prod_{k=1}^n(1+a_k)\leq1+2\sum_{k=1}^n a_k$

Tags: sequences-and-series, inequality, summation, products

I want to prove
$$\prod_{k=1}^n(1+a_k)\leq1+2\sum_{k=1}^n a_k$$
if $\sum_{k=1}^n a_k\leq1$ and $a_k\in[0,+\infty)$

I have no idea where to start, any advice would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Have you tried induction? Seems like the most natural and logical way to start.

Comment: @windircursed Have _you_ tried induction? The obvious induction argument doesn't quite work when I try it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simple induction would work with no problem *if* we were given that $\sum a_k\le 1/2$. Which is enough for the presumed application to infinite products, but doesn't solve the current problem.

Hint for the problem as given: $$\log(1+t)\le t\quad(t\ge0)$$
and $$\log(1+2t)\ge t\quad(0\le t\le 1).$$

You can prove both these by writing the logarithm as the integral of $ds/s$. **Oops**, no you can't. There was a bit of nonsense in the proof I had in mind.

The first inequality is clear; if $t>0$ then $$\log(1+t)=\int_1^{1+t}\frac{ds}s\le\int_1^{1+t}\,ds=t.$$   The second is slightly more subtle. The second derivative of $\log(1+t)$ is negative; hence $\log(1+t)/t$ is a decreasing function of $t>0$, so $$\frac{\log(1+2t)}{t}\ge\log(3)>1\quad(0<t\le 1).$$The same argument shows that in fact $$\log(1+(e-1)t)\ge t\quad(0\le t\le 1),$$giving the sharper inequality Winther noted: $$\log\left(\prod(1+a_k)\right)=\sum\log(1+a_k)\le\sum a_k\le\log\left(1+(e-1)\sum a_k\right).$$

Comment: Oh really? What's the problem?

Comment: I'm not quite sure how to use your hints.
I tried induction but now I'm stuck at $\prod_{k=1}^n (1+a_k)\leq 2$

Comment: @ntm Induction doesn't work! I said so! (Ok, who knows whether there's some inductive argument that works, but the obvious induction simply does not work.) Take the logarithm of both sides of the inequality and you should see the relevance of the hints. You'll also need the fact that the logarithm of a product is the sum of the logarithms...

Comment: oh... so it leads to this: $log(\prod_{k=1}^n (1+a_k))=\sum_{k=1}^n log(1+a_k)\leq \sum_{k=1}^n a_k\leq log(1+2\sum_{k=1}^n a_k)$

Comment: @ntm Right. This is where you click on the little arrow and the little checkmark, btw...

Comment: @Winther Huh? My answer _does_ answer the question. He didn't accept it until he saw this. Is your problem with the two inequalities about the logarithm, or with how they answer the question? (Regarding the second, see the OP's comment.)

Comment: My appologies; I'll remove the comment. I read it as the whole answer refering to assuming $\sum a_k \leq 1/2$ which I now see is not the case at all. Again sorry for the accusation (+1).

Comment: @Winther I just edited the answer so you can change your vote if necessary. Wtf the deal is with those two downvotes I don't know...

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich I did not downvote you; and upvoted you when I added my comment. I don't know; there are like 5 deleted answeres and in those situations I have seen before that people tend to be a bit childish.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich I don't get how to prove those two inequalities about the logarithm. What exactly does "by writing the logarithm as the integral of ds/s" mean - something like this: $ln|1+x|=\int\frac{dx}{1+x}$? How do I prove, that this is $\leq x$?

Comment: @ntm Ok, try this one.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich I don't really understand the argument "The second derivative of log(1+t) is negative; hence log(1+t)/t is a decreasing function of t>0". I know, that if the first derivative of $\frac{log 1+t}{t}$ is negative it has to be a decreasing function, but how can I conclude that from the second derivative of $log 1+t$ being negative?

Comment: @ntm Say $f(t)=\log(1+t)$. Since $f(0)=0$, $f(t)=\int_0^tf'(s)ds$. A change of variable shows $f(t)/t = \int_0^1 f'(st)\,ds$. That's a decreasing function of $t$, since for each $s$ the function $t\mapsto f'(st)$ is decreasing. (Draw a picture; this is all just _convexity_.)

Answer (score 1):

David C. Ullrich's answer shows a very simple way to do this. Here is an altenative which is more complicated but which can allows us to derive a sharper inequality if needed. We treat the problem as an optimization problem of maximizing the product $P = \prod_{k=1}^n(1+a_k)$ over $a_k\geq 0$ under the constraint $S = \sum_{k=1}^n a_k = r$ for some $0\leq r \leq 1$.

We put up the Lagrangian
$$L = P - \lambda(r-S)$$

The extemal point satisfies

$$\frac{\partial L}{\partial a_i} = \frac{P}{1+a_i} - \lambda \implies 1+a_i = \frac{P}{\lambda} \implies a_1=a_2=\ldots = \frac{r}{n}$$
This is a local maximum and we can rule out the possibillity of any maximum points lying on the boundary $a_i = 0$ so the point is a global maximum. This shows that

$$\max_{\matrix{\{a_i\}_{i=1}^n\in[0,\infty)\\\sum a_k = r}}\prod_{k=1}^n(1+a_k) = \left(1+\frac{r}{n}\right)^n \leq e^r$$

so the problem reduces to showing that $1+2r-e^r\geq 0$ for $r\in[0,1]$ which follows by, say, using Taylors theorem.

---

By the same approach we can deduce the slightly stronger result

$$\prod_{k=1}^n(1+a_k) \leq 1 + \frac{e^r-1}{r}\sum_{k=1}^n a_k~~~\text{when}~~~\sum_{k=1}^n a_k \leq r \leq 1$$
in particular for $r=1$ which is the problem at hand we can reduce the constant $2$ down to $e-1 \simeq 1.71$.

Comment: What I did gives $e-1$ just as well. Otoh I'm glad you mentioned this; thinking about it I noticed that the argument I had for the main inequality needed to be fixed.